# DecimalFormat not giving expected format (Indian Number System)

Tags: java, decimalformat

Here is the code.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double number = 10000000;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##,###");
        System.out.println(df.format(number));
    }
}
```

I am getting following output.

```
10,000,000
```

But, I want it like this.

```
1,00,00,000
```

Comment: What are You trying to do its unless

Comment: I didn't get you, what you are trying to say!

Comment: I'm new java but would like to throw in a suggestion. Have you looked at using Locale such as "en_IN"(for India) and see if it formats the number in the way you want. There is an example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#toLocalizedPattern() - keep search for this string "// Print out a number using the localized number, integer, currency," on the page.

Comment: Well, I've tried the locale with both en_IN and hi_IN. It also gives the same output with same grouping size.

Comment: @Akshat read this java doc i think you understand better http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: @S.SWAIN Yes, I've read it. And, I think, what I am trying to achieve is not possible through DecimalFormat. I've to try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I did some work around.

Parsing the string and inserting commas is a nice idea.
But, I thought, the code will be a bit long & dirty.

As, grouping size remains constant in `DecimalFormat`. I separated both parts, formatted them with different patterns and concat both. Here is the code.

```
public static String format(double value) {
    if(value < 1000) {
        return format("###.##", value);
    } else {
        double hundreds = value % 1000;
        int other = (int) (value / 1000);
        return format(",##", other) + ',' + format("000.##", hundreds);
    }
}

private static String format(String pattern, Object value) {
    return new DecimalFormat(pattern).format(value);
}
```

So, for code below:

```
System.out.println(format(999));
System.out.println(format(393.12));
System.out.println(format(13920003.67));
System.out.println(format(1.83));
```

Output will be like this:

```
999
393.12
1,39,20,003.67
1.83
```

Answer (score 1):

DecimalFormat doesn't use that pattern, the grouping size is constant, and is 3 in your case.

From the Javadoc:

> The grouping size is a constant number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for 100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000.
>   If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the
>   interval between the last one and the end of the integer is the one
>   that is used. So "#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Then, how to achieve this pattern?

Comment: If it is simply an integer, just basic Substring is enough: `code`
        int number = 10000000;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##");
        System.out.println(df.format(number/10)+number%10);
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Works as expected. From javadoc:

The grouping separator is commonly used for thousands, but in some countries it separates ten-thousands. The grouping size is a constant number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for 100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000. If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval between **the last one** and the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####".

Possible ugly and error prone solution:

```
private static String customFormat(double number, int[] patterns, char devider) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    String nString = new StringBuilder().append(df.format(number)).reverse().toString();
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = patterns.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        nString = nString.substring(0, position + patterns[i]) + devider + nString.substring(position + patterns[i]);
        position += (patterns[i] + 1);
    }

    return new StringBuilder(nString).reverse().toString();
}
```

Call with: `customFormat(100000000, new int[]{2,2,3}, ',')`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that crosses my mind is this:

```
Make a set of positions on which you want to insert your comma after. For your case, (0, 2, 4).  
Create new StringBuilder.  
Iterate over characters in a string and add them to string builder.
    Peek the stack with comma positions.
    If you're at that position, pop the number from stack and put comma in string builder.
Append decimal separator to string builder
Append decimal part of the original number
```

It's not so fast, it's probably prone to errors, but it's a start.

Comment: Hmm, but Iteration have to be done starting from unit digit to the left of number. As, number can be small (1,000) or big (1,23,45,67,890). Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Is the number in 2nd case 1234567890.0 or 1234567.890?
In any case, instead of iterating from the start and having the commas go from start to end, just reverse the process.

Answer (score 0):

JDK's DecimalFormat doesn't support secondary grouping; ICU does:

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TestIcu {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
    System.out.println(format.format(10000000));
  }
}
```

See full details at ICU's `DecimalFormat` javadoc: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html